# Call function for salary rule on Payroll

Tags: python, odoo

I want to call my function for salary rule, but getting error like "Wrong python code defined for salary rule"

My python code in 'hr.payslip' model is:

```
@api.multi
def _get_project_split(self, project):
    for line in self.all_project_hours:
        if line.project_id.name == project:
            project_split = line.project_split
    return project_split
```

And my salary rule python code is for example:

```
result = payslip.env['hr.payslip']._get_project_split('API')
```

'API' is my project name.

Any help is appreciated

---EDIT---

I use Odoo 12 and I tried from odoo console it works properly when I run for troubleshoot purpose:

```
payslip = env['hr.payslip'].search([('id', '=', '6')])
payslip._get_project_split('API')
```

output: `83.3333333333333`

Also this works from console:

```
payslip.pool.get("hr.payslip")._get_project_split(payslip, 'API')
```

output:    83.3333333333333

But when I put one of these to my salary rule like

1:

```
split = payslip.pool.get("hr.payslip")._get_project_split(payslip, 'API')
result = contract.wage * split / 100
```

or

2:

```
split = payslip._get_project_split('API')
result = contract.wage * split / 100
```

I get an error for this salary rule. I suspect it is a bug.

and my code in 'hr.payslip' model is like

```
class hr_payslip(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'


    @api.multi
    def _get_project_split(self, project):
        for line in self.all_project_hours:
            if line.project_id.name == project:
                project_split = line.project_split
        return project_split
```

Comment: can we see error output.

Comment: Error output is ""Wrong python code defined for salary rule""

Comment: Did you need only the last record that satisfy the condition `line.project_id.name == project`?

Comment: yes, in my salary rule I want to specify my project name in function like i.e `_get_project_split('API')` and while satisfying `line.project_id.name == project` I want to get this line's `project_split` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pool` to get `hr.paysplip` and call `_get_project_split` method.

```
    def _get_project_split(self, cr, uid, payslip, project):
        # Your code
        # return a number
```

And the `python code` of the `salary rule` should be:

```
payslip.pool.get("hr.payslip")._get_project_split(payslip.cr, payslip.uid, payslip,'API')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I still get the same error unfortunately. And I don't know where to debug from logs for salary rule

Comment: I tested the code above and it works so I think that the error probably comes from another salary rule.

Comment: It is not working, I see name of salary rule in error, so I am sure that it is not working for me

Comment: Can you show the salary rule code and the version of Odoo you are using?

Comment: thank you for your interest. I edited my question with required info

Comment: Try to put it on one line

Comment: Which Odoo version are you using?